# Login Failures, Two different Accounts

Tags: support, openid, login

I originally logged with Technorati.  Apparenly, it no longer works for OpenID.  I registered my email as there.  Can't login at all.

Now, I have my account logged in with Google.  I try to edit my Profile and put in my email address and it says, "Can't that email is already registered.  I had gotten a few points on the other account, but at this point I don't care.  I just want to login and have my account have the proper email address.

How can I get this fixed?

Thanks,  Glen

Comment: Stay here and wait or flag for moderation attention or email the team ("contact us" link on every page of the trilogy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email the address provided at the bottom of every page linked as **contact us** -- please include your user page URL